# Gradient-descent and Hidden Markov Models

Tags: probability, optimization, markov-chains, bayesian-network

I would like to use gradient-descent to fit the parameters of a simple 2-state HMM. This paper

- Levinson, S. E., Rabiner, L. R. and Sondhi, M. M. (1983), *[An Introduction to the Application of the Theory of Probabilistic Functions of a Markov Process to Automatic Speech Recognition](http://www3.alcatel-lucent.com/bstj/vol62-1983/articles/bstj62-4-1035.pdf)*. Bell System Technical Journal, 62: 1035–1074. doi: [10.1002/j.1538-7305.1983.tb03114.x](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/j.1538-7305.1983.tb03114.x)

shows derivations of the partial derivatives required for gradient descent, but I am having trouble following the steps. Namely, the paper starts by stating that:

$$P(\mathbf{O}|\mathbf{M})=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\alpha_{t}(i)a_{ij}b_{j}(O_{t+1})\beta_{t+1}(j)$$

for any $t$ such that $1 \leq t \leq T-1$, where $\mathbf{O} = O_1...O_T$ are the observations and $\mathbf{M}$ represents the transition and emission matrices. $\alpha$ is the forward probability and $\beta$ is the backwards probability. $a_{ij}$ is the probability of transition from state $i$ to state $j$ and $b_j(O_{t+1})$ is the probability of observing $O_{t+1}$ given state $j$. Finally, $N$ is the number of states.

To run gradient descent, one needs to calculate the partial derivatives with respect to model parameters. The paper derives:

$$\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{a_{ij}}}=\sum_{t=1}^{T-1}\alpha_t(i)b_j(O_{t+1})\beta_{t+1}(j)$$

But the exact steps for reaching this formula are not shown. Can anyone elaborate on how this result was obtained?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you comfortable with how [partial differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) works?

Comment: Yes. But this formula is difficult for me because both forward and backward probabilities are recursive functions of $a_{ij}$. So things get messy very quickly when applying the product rule. Also, note that the summation in the second formula is different from the first. I suppose I could do a full symbolic expansion and convince myself, but I would like to see if there is a cleaner way of getting the partial derivative.

Answer (score 1):

For the update equations, they treat $\alpha, \beta$, and $b_j$ as independent of $a_{ij}$. If you see it this way I am sure you will see how they get the partials. I think their derivation could have been better myself. For example, they could have arrived at (27) from (26) by moving $\lambda$ to the other side without multiplying by $a_{ij}$ and summing over $j$. Maybe I'm missing something, but I really think they could have gone a step further and saved a lot of people a lot of headscratching.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  You might be interested in learning $\LaTeX$ and posting with math formulas using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as supported on this site.